# Filter data based on date/time range and matching id

Tags: r, list, filtering

I am trying to filter a dataset based on the date/time range (start and end time) and the id of each row from another dataset. The end result should be a list of filtered data frames.

Below is the code to create the two data sets.

```
#This is the dataset to filter 
x <- as.data.frame(format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 07:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 11:50"), by = "10 min"))) #date/time
y <- as.data.frame(format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 07:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 11:50"), by = "10 min"))) #date/time

datetime <- rbind(list(x,y))
datetime <- do.call(rbind, datetime)
datetime <- rename(datetime, datetime=`format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 07:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 11:50"), by = "10 min"))`)
datetime

values <- c(1:60) #value 
id <- vector(mode="character", length=60)
#id <- rep(letters[1:5], 6) #id 

dataloggers <- data.frame(datetime, values, id)
head(dataloggers)

dataloggers[c(1:10), 3] ="a"
dataloggers[c(11:30), 3]="b"
dataloggers[c(31:60), 3]="c"

dataloggers$datetime <- ymd_hms(dataloggers$datetime)

#and this is the dataset used to filter the dataset above 
starttime <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-01 07:00", "2019-01-01 08:40", "2019-01-01 07:00:00"))
starttime <- ymd_hms(starttime)
datetime <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-01 08:00", "2019-01-01 10:00", "2019-01-01 08:00"))
datetime <- ymd_hms(datetime)
id <- rep(letters[1:3])
data<- data.frame(starttime,datetime, id)
```

I have managed to do this using a `for()` loop to filter the date/time ranges:

```
my_list <- list() #create empty list
for(i in seq_along(data$starttime)) {
 output <-  dataloggers %>% 
    filter(between(dataloggers$datetime, data$starttime[i], data$datetime[i])) 
  my_list[[i]] <- output
}

my_list <- do.call(rbind, my_list)
my_list
```

But as you can see, it only filters the data frame based on the start and end time. I need it to also filter it based on the matching id. `left_join()` doesn't give me what I want because I don't want to merge the datasets. I only want to have a list of filtered dataframes based on those two conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 approaches :

1. Fuzzy joins based on range :

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(dataloggers, data, 
               by = c('id', 'datetime' = 'starttime', 'datetime'), 
               match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
```

2. Join by `id` and keep data in range -

   a. `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
dataloggers %>%
  inner_join(data, by = 'id') %>%
  filter(datetime.x >= starttime & datetime.x <= datetime.y)
```

b. Base R :

```
subset(merge(dataloggers, data, by = 'id'), 
       datetime.x >= starttime & datetime.x <= datetime.y)
```

Comment: Oh yay I got a bronze badge! things are looking up!!!